# При запросе на API через Postman, в параметр метода приходит 0, вместо переданного значения

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

Вот сам метод контроллера:

```
    [HttpPost("verify")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> VerifyAccount(int verifyCode)
    {
        string? Email = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Email");
        string? Password = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Password");
        string? Username = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Username");
        string? Role = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Role");

        if (Email is null || Password is null || Username is null || Role is null)
            return StatusCode(422, new { message = AccountErrorMessage.NullUserData });

        string? code = HttpContext.Session.GetString(Email);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
            return StatusCode(422, new { message = AccountErrorMessage.VerifyCodeNull });

        try
        {
            int correctCode = int.Parse(code);

            if (!_validation.IsSixDigit(correctCode))
                return StatusCode(500, new { message = AccountErrorMessage.Error });

            if (!verifyCode.Equals(correctCode))
                return StatusCode(422, new { message = AccountErrorMessage.CodeIncorrect });

            var userModel = new UserModel { email = Email, password_hash = Password, username = Username, role = Role };
            await _userCreate.Create(userModel);

            HttpContext.Session.Remove(Email);
            HttpContext.Session.Remove("Email");
            HttpContext.Session.Remove("Password");
            HttpContext.Session.Remove("Username");
            HttpContext.Session.Remove("Role");

            return StatusCode(201);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return StatusCode(422, new { message = AccountErrorMessage.InvalidFormatCode });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical(ex.ToString());

            HttpContext.Session.Remove(Email);
            HttpContext.Session.Remove("Email");
            HttpContext.Session.Remove("Password");
            HttpContext.Session.Remove("Username");

            return StatusCode(500, new { message = AccountErrorMessage.Error });
        }
    }
```

Тело запроса в Postman:

```
{
    "verifyCode": 939797
}
```

Content-Type установлен в application/json

Лог из Postman:

```
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.35.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: db2b48d2-7255-4903-8f51-613fefb25620
Host: localhost:7067
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 30
Cookie:     .AspNetCore.Session=CfDJ8Nz4yTn59WtDmbz2eck3COTQuMXqlfMmLer3kUCRJ5g1vIf9%2FakwV%2BtJW9Q7pxgT    hnSOcks6UBusaZl9MqLQz4%2F1OZV4ZRihohKioellu9gdzn6YCn9asaDLOD%2B%2F%2Fh3Doodsmsb0qe5R0vdTtPLq    AuTYTxC0bhPppxlC6jxU%2Fo%2Fa
Request Body
{
    "verifyCode": 939797
}
Response Headers
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 24 Nov 2023 23:08:55 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Response Body
{"message":"Code is incorrect"}
```

Comment: Хм, а что мешает поставить  точку остановки, отправить запрос, и посмотреть какие данные приходят? Увидите наверно, что параметр 0, а раз он там 0, значит вы передаете туда то, что изначально не предназначено, верно? Далее открываете документацию, ищите [раздел про параметры](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api), и видите `По умолчанию веб-API использует следующие правила для привязки параметров: Если параметр является "простым" типом, веб-API пытается получить значение из URI.`, а еще ниже `[FromBody]`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ставил точку остановки, у verifyCode значение 0, я пытался ставить аттрибут **[FromBody]**, в таком случае вообще получал 415 статус код.

Comment: А стоп, я ошибся, если поставить **[FromBody]** то получаю такой ответ от Postman : **{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-17a9ebcd1b3399af118c847b8830dd2f-3667ed19df641352-00","errors":{"$":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."]}}**

Comment: раз вы пометили `int verify` как `[FromBody]`, то нужно передавать число `939797`, а вы передаёте туда объект `{ "verifyCode": 939797
}`

Comment: @iikuzmychov. да все правильно, только что попробовал, все сработало, спасибо. Можете создать ответ на вопрос, я отмечу его как принятый.